# DoneJS - Chat Example failing on add Component

Tags: canjs, donejs

I am following in the *DoneJS* Chat example on the following URL:

http://donejs.com/Guide.html

However, when I get to Step: Generate custom elements, I get the following error:

> C:_source\donejs\donejs-chat>donejs add component home.component
>   chat-home x No 'folder' or 'appName' specified. Neither in your
>   .yo-rc.json nor in your package.json file

I have installed:

- NodeJS 5.5.0
- NPM 3.3.12
- DoneJS 0.6.0
- Bootstrap 3.3.6

Any ideas on what is wrong and/or how to resolve the issue?

Comment: Can you run `donejs add component` without any of the other parameters? Also, can you supply the contents of your .yo-rs.json file in your project root, also the "name" property in your package.json.

Comment: So we just noticed an issue with the donejs generators in v0.6.0. Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling. You should be able to just reinstall the generators: `npm install generator-donejs`

Answer (score 0):

Hello yes i know whats going on there was some bugs that are solved now plz retry the current versions.